# Querying big databases with Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, sql-server, odbc

Is it possible to use Excel's pivot table as a kind of query builder against a database, without copying the entire database into Excel?  I know that with the External Data Sources feature, you can connect to any ODBC database and create a pivot table out of the results from any SQL query.  But at least with MySQL / ODBC, it seems to do this by copying the entire result set onto the local machine and then running the queries locally.

Is there a way to get the same functionality where the queries actually happen on the server, say by using Microsoft SQL server?  My problem is that I want to be able to analyze data using pivottables, but the whole database table is too big to load into excel.

Answer (score 3):

Even if you did copy the entire database (which would be incredibly large most likely), pivot tables are *slow*.  It would take a lot of time to just get the pivot table to go through all of the data and display anything initially (I'm working with a pivot table about 30k rows and 20 columns, and it takes over 10 minutes to just load the file).

It is impossible to use a pivot table with anything other then a defined range of Excel values or a query, but the entire result set needs to be fetched first.  Even if it were possible to use a pivot table directly with the database, pivot tables need to go through each row of data to parse it - effectively downloading the whole database anyways.

If you need Pivot Table functionality in your queries, look at the [`PIVOT` and `UNPIVOT` commands for MS SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx), or if you're using MS Access, try using a cross-tab query to get you started.  As a last resort, just filter out the rows and columns you don't need from the database before you start your pivot table.

Comment: Re: "impossible" - not true.  When connecting to an external data source through ODBC you can send the data straight to a pivot table and never have the raw data visible in your worksheet.  The bummer is that the full set of data appears to reside in excel somewhere anyway.

Comment: @Leopd that's what I was getting at, but I updated my answer to be more explicit.